# Resizing a square in Java

Tags: java, resize, shapes, drag, mouselistener

I am having an annoying problem trying to resize a draggable square in Java.  To resize the square I am checking to see if the mouse cursor is inside a rectangular area surrounding the bottom right hand corner of the square - if it is, then the square resizes when I drag the mouse.  This code works fine, BUT if I then click on the square to drag it around the screen, it jumps back to the default size of 100 x 100.

My class starts off like this:

```
public class DragPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, 
MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener
{

Graphics2D g2;
Rectangle2D square;
Color colour;

double x1, y1, x2, y2, sizex, sizey;
double offsetX, offsetY;
double oldx, oldy;

boolean dragging = false;
boolean resizing = false;

public DragPanel()
{

    x1 = 10.0;
    y1 = 10.0;
    sizex = 100.0;
    sizey = 100.0;
    x2 = x1 + sizex;
    y2 = y1 + sizey;

    square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex, sizey);
    colour = Color.BLUE;

    setFocusable(true);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseWheelListener(this);
    this.requestFocus();

}
```

Here are my Mouse Pressed and Mouse Dragged Methods:

1. Mouse Pressed:

   ```
   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) 
   {
   double mx = ev.getX();
   double my = ev.getY();

   if (mx > x1 && mx < x2 && my > y1 && my < y2)
   {
       dragging = true;
       offsetX  = mx - x1;
       offsetY = my - y1;

   }

   if (mx > x2 - 3 && mx < x2 + 3 && my > y2 - 3 && my < y2 + 3)
   {
       oldx = mx;
       oldy = my;
       resizing = true;

   }

   }
   ```
2. Mouse Dragged:

   ```
   @Override
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) 
   {
   if (dragging)
   {
       double mx = ev.getX();
       double my = ev.getY();

       x1 = mx - offsetX;
       y1 = my - offsetY;
       x2 = x1 + sizex;
       y2 = y1 + sizey;

       square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex, sizey);
       repaint();  
   }

   if (resizing)
   {
       double mx = ev.getX();
       double my = ev.getY();

       double diffx, diffy;

       diffx = oldx - mx;
       diffy = oldy - my;

       square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex - diffx, sizey - diffy);
       repaint();

   }


   }
   ```

The code you see above does what I want it to do in terms of resizing, but as I already explained, DOESN'T work properly when I try and drag the square after resizing.  And I know why - it is because of THIS line:

```
square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex - diffx, sizey - diffy);
```

So my solution was to change the last part of the `if (resizing)` block as follows:

```
        diffx = oldx - mx;
        diffy = oldy - my;
        sizex -= diffx;
        sizey -= diffy;

square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex, sizey);
repaint();
```

When I do this however, the thing stops working!  I can still drag the square, but if I try and resize, the movement is erratic and extreme.

WHAT am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should be adding it instead of subtracting diffx/y from sizex/y

Comment: Tried that @TylerOsborne, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the conditions for dragging and resizing are not mutually exclusive, particularly close to the borders. Assuming you are putting these two flags to false on mouse release, a single mouse click or move could still go into both modes at once.

I would put `else if (mx > x2 - 3 && mx < x2 + 3 && my > y2 - 3 && my < y2 + 3)` and `else if (resizing)` to avoid any intended consequences. This would make any dragging a priority over any resizing.

Being a graphical thing, hard to say if this is your problem (or part of it), but give it can't hurt to clear this up.

---

Edit: Of course, you might want to do the resize conditions take priority over (go before) the drag condition, since the area for resizing is much smaller than the area for dragging.

---

Edit 2: BTW, when you resize you are modifying your `square`, but not your `sizex` and `sizey` variables. Naturally, when you ask for those values when dragging they are the same as before (100). Store the changes and it should work. On that note, it is probably a bad idea to have multiple representations of the same information. It causes redundancies and synchronization issues like this one. If possible, remove these variables: `double x1, y1, x2, y2, sizex, sizey;` and read/write then from the current state of square (you probably don't need a new square every time either).

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and then I could still drag the square but couldn't resize!  I have reverted back and now the resize works, but the square still jumps back to the default size (100 x 100) if I click inside it after resizing.  There HAS to be SOME way to tell the square to keep its new size after being resized, but seemingly the way I thought of doing it doesn't actually work!

Comment: That WAS the expected behavior. You probably don't want to do both at once. Well, you need to define the areas for drag and resize well. Let me edit to be clearer...

Comment: Ok, I took your advice and put the resize conditions before the drag conditions.  Now I can both drag and resize the square but I am still having the same problem as before (i.e if I leave the last line as `square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex - diffx, sizey - diffy);` then the square jumps back to 100 x 100 when I drag after resizing).

Comment: I thought I was "storing the changes" to my size variable. Isn't that the point of "sizex -= diffx" and "sizey -= diffy"?  Clearly I'm not permitted to store them that way though!

Comment: Yes, you are when you do that fix, but not on the original. Did you try both my original solution AND that?

Comment: I did, and it still didn't work. I even tried putting the "sizex -= diffx" and "sizey -= diffy" in a different place. Nothing works, and I'm seriously considering going back to my original plan - resizing using the mouse wheel, which thankfully DOES work.  Thank you for your bold effort anyway, was much appreciated.

Comment: MMM, it should work. Unless the problem is outside the code you pasted. You seem to have a grasp of the solution. My advice: copy the file and start over, delete those extra variables that are just polluting the code. Just keep `square` as the only representation of state and see it it works. Sometimes the problem is trivial, but hard to spot since you've read over it many times. --- As for thanks, you can always upvote and/or accept ;-) At the very least, it should help others looking for unanswered questions to find where they can help.

Answer (score 0):

I treat these a two separate functions:

1. Check out the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/)
2. and the [Component Resizer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/)

The code in these classes is more complex than you need but you may want to consider the separation of the logic for each function in your final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, or rather, I found *a* solution.  I changed my `if (resizing)` statement within the `mouseDragged` method as follows:

Old:

```
    if (resizing)
    {
        double mx = ev.getX();
        double my = ev.getY();

        double diffx, diffy;

        diffx = oldx - mx;
        diffy = oldy - my;

        square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, sizex - diffx, sizey - diffy);
        repaint();

    }
```

New:

```
    if (resizing)
    {
        double mx = ev.getX();
        double my = ev.getY();

        x2 = mx - rOffX;
        y2 = my - rOffX;

        sizex = x2 - x1;
        sizey = sizex;

        square.setRect(x1, y1, sizex, sizey);
        repaint();

    }
```